# CSS rule is executed with and without :not() selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm having a really strange problem with my Sass/CSS. I have a rule that is executed with and without the :not() selector, but I don't think it should be applied with :not().

This runs:

```
.background-color-white {
    .breadcrumbs-primer {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        li, a, li:after, li a:after {
            color: $color-white;
        }
    }
}
```

But so does this:

```
:not(.background-color-white) {
    .breadcrumbs-primer {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        li, a, li:after, li a:after {
            color: $color-white;
        }
    }
}
```

and `.breadcrumbs-primer` is nested inside `.background-color-white` in my HTML as you can see here:

```
<div class="background-color-white">
   <!-- breadcrumbs -->
   <div class="breadcrumbs-primer padding-top-small">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="small-12 columns">
            <ul class="breadcrumbs">
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li class="disabled">Lorem ipsum dolar</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- end breadcrumbs -->
</div>
```

Comment: because there is for example the body that match the :not() selector ... use direct child selector and it won't work

Comment: @boltclock i was pretty sure there was a dup but didn't find it .. and now i wasted my time writing half a similar answer to yours :p

Comment: Thanks @boltclock, I couldn't find that post. I fixed it by putting `.container` before `:not()` resulting in `.container :not(.background-color-white) .breadcrumbs-primer .breadcrumbs` but I will look into that question's answer :)